# Получение свойств дочерних элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Приветствую всех.

Есть html код:

```
<div id="my_el">
  <div id="child" some_prop="value">
    Содержимое элемента
  </div>
  <div id="child2" some_prop2="value2">
    Содержимое элемента2
  </div>
</div>
```

И есть объект jQuery:

```
var my_obj = $('#my_el');
```

Как, используя этот объект, получить свойства some_prop (или some_prop2) одного из элементов #child (или #child2) ?

Comment: my_obj.children('#child').attr('some_prop');

Comment: @Deonis, могли бы и в качестве ответа это написать, а то как же я ваш коммент за ответ приму?)

Comment: @Deonis, как оказалось, проблема не совсем решена..
var str = $('#upload').attr('value');
var str2 = document.getElementById('upload').value;
console.log('str: ' + str); // undefined
console.log('str2: ' + str2); // всё ок
Не подскажете, что может быть не так?

Comment: @LightShock, давайте без абстрактных примеров. На [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) выкладывайте реальную часть html-кода и объясните, какие данные хотите получить из элементов.Потому, что если элемент с *id = upload* - это поле формы, то получать данные в jQuery надо при помощи метода **.val()**. Т.е. вот так:    var str = $('#upload').val();

Comment: @Deonis, вот: http://jsfiddle.net/N9qk8/2/
Хочу получить значение атрибута value элемента #upload.

Comment: Ну, так [это именно то](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/N9qk8/3/), о чем я написал в предыдущем комменте. )

Comment: @Deonis, ох, прошу прощения, почему-то не обратил на это внимания. Спасибо ещё раз)
Интересно, почему метод attr() не даёт доступ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если some_prop действительно так выглядит, то это противоречит стандарту, в html5 для этого введен аттрибут data-PropertyName, а в jquery работа с этим аттрибутом (чтение первоначальное) реализована через $.data();

т.о вам для начала надо заменить some_prop на

data-prop="value"

и так:

HTML:

```
<div id="my_el">
  <div class="el_childo" data-prop="value">
    Содержимое элемента
  </div>
  <div class="el_childo" data-prop="value2">
    Содержимое элемента2
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $object=$('#my_el'),
    $childs=$object.children('.el_childo'),
    prop1=$childs.eq(0).data('prop'),
    prop2=$childs.eq(1).data('prop');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/8dDSz/

имейте ввиду что метод data() для обновления data не обновляет аттрибут в html, а использует внутреннее хранилище jquery.

т.е. данные сохраненные с пом-ю `childs.eq(0).data('prop','new_value');` можно будет прочитать только используя `data()`

Comment: Ну нет конечно. some_prop, как следует из названия, это всего лишь некое свойство некого элемента.

Comment: тогда $element.prop('property'), либо $element.attr('attrubute'); весь вопрос в том, стандартный это атрибут или нет. если нет, то следуйте моим рекомендациям с data

Comment: Это стандартный атрибут. Но, опять же, мне нужно получить доступ к атрибутам потомков, а не самого элемента.

Вообще, Deonis уже ответил в комментах, но так как его коммент я не могу взять в качестве ответа => приму ваш :)

Comment: @LightShock, мой ответ правильный в рамках заданного вами вопроса и спорить об адекватности поставленной задачи мне не хотелось. А @eicto взял эту миссию на себя и ответил в полном объеме. Правнуки, наткнувшись на этот вопрос, получат правильный развернутый ответ. Так что, вы не прогадали с принятием. ;)

Comment: @Deonis, тоже так думаю)